# django model serialization

Tags: django, json, serialization, models

I want to serialize models so:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
   Title = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class ScheduleEvent1(models.Model):
   ScheduleContent = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
   Description = models.TextField()

class ScheduleEvent2(models.Model):
   ScheduleContent = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
   AnotherField = models.TextField()
   ShortDescription = models.TextField()
```

make smth like `serializers.serialize('json', Schedule.objects.all())`

The result likes

```
[
{
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "Schedule",
    "fields": {
        "Title": "Some Title",
        "ScheduleEvent1": [
            {
                "pk": 19,
                "model": "ScheduleEvent1",
                "fields": {
                    "Description": "Some Descr",
                }
            },
            {
                "pk": 20,
                "model": "ScheduleEvent1",
                "fields": {
                    "Description": "Some Descr2222",
                }
            }
        ],
        "ScheduleEvent2": [
            {
                "pk": 15,
                "model": "ScheduleEvent2",
                "fields": {
                    "AnotherField": "Some text",
                    "ShortDescription" : "Some text ...",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

]

In general. I have entity tree. And I need serialize this tree from root.

tnx for help.

Comment: What problem do you have?  That's pretty easy to do in Django.  It's even easier if you use Piston. Please post your code and the errors you're getting.

Comment: Oh. I don't know how can I make this :( Could you show the example code?

Comment: In my example i have only part of my tree. Actually the depth of the tree may be greater than 2.

Comment: @Andrey: 1) Query. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/  2) Serialize.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/  I don't need to provide code.  It's already in the documentation for Django.  What problem do you have?   Please post your code and the errors you're getting.

Comment: I've read the documentation. I can serialize this example. But I can't serialize more complex case in which: 1) More than two different ScheduleEvent models (ScheduleEvent3, ScheduleEvent4, ScheduleEvent5, ScheduleEvent6,...); 2) The depth of the tree greater than 2. Schedule has Session = models.ForeignKey(Session), Session has OneMoreModel = models.ForeignKey(OneMoreModel). And I want to write smth like serializers.serialize('json', OneMoreModel.objects.all()) and get full json.

Comment: @Andrey: "Please post your code and the errors you're getting".

Comment: @S.Lott: I have no code for complex case. So I want you to give me example.

Comment: @Andrey: Your question has code.  It also has a sting "smth" which isn't a word.  I don't know what that is, it's not code either.  You have some code.  The code works?  Doesn't work?  What does the code do?  What **specific** problem do you have with the code you've written so far?

Comment: @S.Lott: I have no a specific code. I've done research. I found [link](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers). This serialization works from child to parent serializers.serialize('json', ScheduleEvent1.objects.all()), but I need from parent to child (serializers.serialize('json', Schedule.objects.all())).

Comment: @Andrey: "This serialization works from".  Does that mean you have some code which works?  If so, update the question with the code that works.  Explain what doesn't work by **updating** the question to show what's wrong with that code.  I cannot imagine your code.  I cannot guess what you've written.  I cannot see how it's wrong, because I cannot see the code you write which "works from child to parent".  Words mean very little.  Code actually means something.  Please **update** the question with some code to explain whatever problem you're having.  Please.  Please be **specific**.

Comment: btw, is there a way to hide "model" field from the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/#dependencies-during-serialization

Covers the essence of this.  The resulting file is not *precisely* what's required, since the objects won't be nested.  However it is what Django produces by default and it's what Django will use for deserialization.

If you use [Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!emitters) you can easily define a Handler which will produce nested JSON, but it won't be *precisely* as shown because Piston's JSON emitter isn't precisely in the Django format.

Getting to *precisely* what's hoped-for leads to extending the Django serializer to produce a nested JSON object as the natural key. See http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/serializers/python.py.  Lines 47-59

Or, you can define a `natural_key` method which uses Django's 'django.core.serializers.json .Serializer` to emit the JSON serialization of the object instead of some other natural key value.  This is a little weird semantically, but it may do what you want.

Comment: Tnx for help. I will use Piston.