# serialize model to use with Chart.js in Django

Tags: python, django

even though I have seen a lot of resource about similar topics, nothing has been able to solve my issue. the closest were [How do I JSON serialize a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798111/how-do-i-json-serialize-a-python-dictionary) and [django model serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024279/django-model-serialization).

I am trying to plot a graph from a model on my frontend with Chart.js and I cannot get my view to be serialized and being able to fit the arguments for the graph. I attach my model.py, view.py and htlm page as well as the error that I get.

models.py

```
class Classification(models.Model):
    Class = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    inventory_dollars = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Class


class ClassificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Classification
        fields = "__all"
```

views.py

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'dashboard/charts.html', {})



class ChartData(APIView):
    authentification_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = Classification.Class
        default_items = Classification.inventory_dollars
        data = {
            "labels" : labels,
            "default": default_items
        }

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = 'application/javascript; charset=utf8')
```

html

```
{%  extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}

<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data1){
        labels = data1.labels
        defaultData = data1.default
        setChart()


    },
    error: function(error_data){

        console.log(error_data)
    }}
)

function setChart(){

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');

    var mychart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
        type: 'polarArea',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: defaultData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }


        }
    })


    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: defaultData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    })}

{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}



<div class ='row'>
    <div class="clo-sm-12">
        <h1>Inventory Management Dashboard</h1>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
        <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

As you can see i need to find a way to specify "labels" and "default" in my view in order to be plotted then in the html file. Here is the error that I get so far:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chart/data
Django Version: 3.0.4
Python Executable: /Users/pierre/Desktop/Django-app/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.1
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Users/pierre/Desktop/inventory3/dashboard/views.py", line 67, in get
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = 'application/javascript; charset=utf8')
  File "/Users/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  ...

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/chart/data
Exception Value: Object of type Manager is not JSON serializable
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data
```

how can I solve this? Thank you for any help

I am new to Django and I really don't know what to do no more.

update: thanks to @dirkgroten advice, i changed my view to this:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    authentification_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        labels = Classification.objects.all().values_list('Class', flat=True)
        default_items = Classification.objects.all().values_list('inventory_dollars', flat=True)
        data = {
            "labels" : labels,
            "default": default_items
        }

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = 'application/javascript; charset=utf8')
```

which now gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: It's not clear where exactly this error happens, you need to show the part or the error trace that tells us on which line of code the error happens. Also `Classification.Class` or `Classification.inventory_dollars` are the class attributes, not the values from your db. And nowhere are you using your `ClassificationSerializer` which would seem the appropriate thing to do since you're using django-rest-framework.

Comment: Ok I updated my question with the traceback. Regarding the serializer, this is what I don't get, how can I use the serializer while respecting the arguments for the graph

Comment: ok, fair point, if you need to just send back two lists of values, then you don't necessarily need a serializer. But you still need to make a query to fetch the objects in your db and create the lists. Like `labels = Classification.objects.all().values_list('Class', flat=True)`

Comment: got it, thank you, your advice + modifying the return statement to simply 'return Response(data) did it. thanks! if you want to make it as answer i'll gladly accept it

Comment: Did it work for you? Cause I maybe see what is wrong with your json data

Comment: it worked by doing what i wrote above. not sure if this is a proper way to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps()` will only accept a python `list` or a python `dict`. Also, inside the `dict` and `list` you can only use `dict`, `list` and the primitive python types `str`, `int` and `float`.

So you can't just pass it just your model instances, unless you serialise them first (which is what your `ClassificationSerializer` does). But in fact, it seems your graph API just want two lists of values, so you should fetch them using `labels = Classification.objects.values_list('Class', flat=True)`.

Finally, this returns a `QuerySet` (`labels`), so you need to make it a `list` first: `list(labels)`.

Note: I would strongly advise you to rename your field `Class` to something else with lowercase. Indeed you cannot call it `class` because it's a reserved keyword, but attributes in python should be lowercase. Your naming is making for hard-to-read code.